# sending Satoshi to a output of a unconfirmed transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

this is a hypothetical question, reason is that my own incoming transaction is stuck because of another ancestor transaction that is already in mempool. for almost 1 day.

since I am neither the sender or receiver of this transaction that is stuck. would it be still possible for me to send coins to the output of the unconfirmed transaction with a higher fee so that the one that is in limbo due to low fees will pass through?

I have a full bitcoin node running locally. however I don't have mining power to mine those stuck transaction. so i am looking for alternatives.

Thanks in advance

why I don't just to CPFP on my own is because mine hasn't reached mempool yet, I get the pending que from chain.so which is hashflare.io private block chain gui which includes pending widthtawals

Comment: Do you own the recipient output?

Comment: nope, but I was thinking that somehow I could target one of that outputs of that unconfirmed transaction as a output on my transaction. or such concept doesn't exist?

Comment: under the impression that outputs consists of address + some sort of a positional entry in the ledger

Comment: my output is 1000 transactions behind the one that is stuck and its not even on the mempool, sad situation where mining operator company who claims to be expert in crypto is unable to produce a multi-pay transaction

Comment: I hope that I have more experience to help you but as you said, it's really sad situation.